# Photoshop script to insert an image into a layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, javascript, script

I am using Photoshop and Photopea to streamline a workflow. Rather than making hundreds of PSD templates I am hoping to use a base template in where a script dynamically adds the right image depending on some conditions.

The part that is difficult is adding a third party image (public image hosted on S3) into a layer via a script. Does anybody know if this is possible? Alternatively I could potentially load the second image dynamically however I that would have to be in a separate project (i.e. another tab), so would need a script to copy paste that layer into an existing layer on my base template.

TLDR: Is it possible for a Photoshop script to load in an image from a web URL?

Comment: Are you using jsx or uxp?